# itext pdf - how to combine headers and data when table splits

Tags: itext

Here is a sample code how I am displaying tables on pdf. Requirement is, when the table is going to split into multiple pages, the last row of this page (highlighted with gray background on the pdf) and the first row of the next page (white background) should displayed as combined. Most of the tables in our pdf have the same design to display multiple sections in a single table. Is it possible..? Please help!

public class PdfTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/SplitExample.pdf"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.open();
    document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
    document.setMargins(36, 36, 60, 36);

    PdfTest pdfTest = new PdfTest();
    pdfTest.createTable(document, writer);
    document.close();
}

private void createTable(Document document, PdfWriter writer) {

    try {

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5);
        float width[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
        table.setWidths(width);
        table.setTotalWidth(527);
        table.setWidthPercentage(90);

        document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        document.add(new Paragraph("Table Header"));
        document.add(new Paragraph("\n"));

        for(int i=0; i<6; i++)  {

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(getNameAndAgeCell("Person ", 25));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting("Date", 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting("Male", 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting("Eglish", 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Benefits", 4));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting("No", 4));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Taxes", 4));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting("Yes", 4));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Date", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Citizen", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Entry", 1));


            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 2));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 2));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 2));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 2));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 2));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 2));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 2));
            table.addCell(buildTabularHeaders("Test", 1));

            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 2));
            table.addCell(wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(null, 1));

        }

        //addNewPage(writer, document, 80, table.getTotalHeight());

        document.add(table);

    } catch (Exception objExp) {
        objExp.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private PdfPCell getNameAndAgeCell(String name, int rowSpan) throws Exception {

    PdfPCell nameAgeCell = new PdfPCell();
    nameAgeCell.addElement(new Phrase("Name", FontFactory.getFont("ARIAL", 9)));
    nameAgeCell.addElement(new Phrase("Age" + "20", FontFactory.getFont("ARIAL", 9)));
    nameAgeCell.setRowspan(rowSpan);

    return nameAgeCell;
}

private PdfPCell wrapStringToPdfPCellWithFormatting(String input, int colSpan) {

    PdfPCell output = null;
    if (input != null) {

        output = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(input, FontFactory.getFont("ARIAL", 9)));
        output.setPadding(1);
        output.setColspan(colSpan);
    } else {
        output = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(INInterfacesHelper.SPACE_STRING , FontFactory.getFont("ARIAL", 9)));
        output.setPadding(1);
        output.setColspan(colSpan);
    }
    //output.setBorder(1);
    return output;
}

private PdfPCell buildTabularHeaders(String strHeaderText, int colSpan) {
    PdfPCell objHeadCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(strHeaderText,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 9,Font.BOLD)));
    //objHeadCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    //objHeadCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    objHeadCell.setGrayFill(0.8f);
    objHeadCell.setColspan(colSpan);
    return objHeadCell;
}

private void addNewPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document, int tableHeaderHeight, float tableHeight) {
    if ((writer.getVerticalPosition(true) - tableHeaderHeight - document.bottom()) < tableHeight) {
        document.newPage();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you add one table after the other, you won't see any difference: visually, the separate tables will look as if they are one.

Hence, you shouldn't use one large table to meet your requirement. Instead, you should start a new table each time you need a new header and use the `setHeaderRows()` method to define how many rows are part of the header. Those rows will be repeated automatically when the table is split.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is just one table which is displaying for example, address information for multiple persons in our application.Each person info is separated in a single table but, because of the design it's looking like multiple tables. Is it possible to find the position of the last row of current page and if it is splitting from it's header, display it in the next page along with data..?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I assume that you are referring to an *ordinary row* using the word *header*. If you're not, using `setHeaderRows()` should work. If you are, please rephrase the question without using the word *header* incorrectly.

Comment: You are correct, I am referring to an ordinary row using the word header. I have edited my question.

Comment: The answer is: it's not possible with ordinary rows, but you can work around it by working with smaller, separate tables where the rows with the gray background are real header rows.

Comment: This gave me some idea... We have identified the large tables in the pdf and changed the design to display them as separate tables in each page and for other tables, we also identified the number of tables that can be fit in each page and if there are more, displaying them in a new page. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Your new design will also improve the performance and the memory use of your application. This deserves a +1 for your question.